# CentOS kernel version 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 bugs

Tags: centos, linux-kernel

As far as I updated my centos ver 6.4 to 6.5, the new kernel (2.6.32-**431**.el6.x86_64) disappointed me! It hangs when I want to plug my external hard to laptop or hangs when I start virtual windows 7 under VMWARE 9.0.1!

I don't have these problems when I boot linux with kernel version 2.6.32-**358**.23.2.el6.x86_64 (Previous version).

Did any one face to these problems? And what is solution?

**Update:** Pluging external hard drive fixed with formating... But booting win7 under vmware in kernel version 431 still remains!

**Update 2:** Problem exist even with updating kernel to 2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.x86_64!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known problem with the 2.6.32-431 kernel. It happens to me on two different computers.

I found a Red Hat support case for it:
https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/629063

And reported at vmware
https://communities.vmware.com/thread/463825

I backed off to the previous kernel until a fixed kernel becomes available.

Comment: Red Hat and CentOS put out a 2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1 kernel today. I don't have the patience to test it right now. If anyone else tries it with vmplayer, please let us know if it fixes the freeze problem.

Comment: Please read Update2 in my post...

Comment: I applied the workaround given in the vmware thread above - the one where you remove some kernel modules and force it to rebuild. It's working great with the 2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1 kernel.

Comment: I executed `vmware-modconfig --console --install-all` but the problem still exist!

Answer (score 2):

I would either downgrade and pin the version of the kernel, (you can do this by excluding that package via the yum `.repo` files), until a future version comes out or download and compile my own version of the kernel.

I've not experienced any issues such as your're explaining with those versions of the Kernel or CentOS 6.5.

Comment: Thank you for your response. No problem with excluding because I never boot my system with this kernel anymore... I think new version has bugs and I have to wait until new version will release!

Comment: @SepahradSalour this answer rather sounds as if you have a specific problem NOT related to this kernel. So you are lowering security for what?

Comment: How did you get this result which is not related to this kernel? I have problem with booting windows 7 in vmware under kernel version 431 yet! But it's ok under previous version...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run the virtual box from GUI. Boot with another kernel version (you can choose the kernel-version from the extended *boot-menu*), sign in as root and do `yum remove kernel-2.6.32-431.1.2.el6.x86_64`. Simple and effective.

Comment: No need to removing kernel, read Update2 in my post...